# JBOSS 7 domain jsp changes not reflecting after restart

Tags: java, jsp, jboss, jboss7.x

I have changed some text in jsps. I tried restarting jboss,
removing war(undeployed) and again deployed. Reboot OS. Still facing issue.

Tried deleting all the content from data directories.

Finally where is that old content coming from?

From past 3 hours I have done deployment many times still of no use.

I am using CLI for deployments

Please do suggest something. In domain mode(clustering enabled). I have shut down other two nodes and running on host. Still I cannot see the changes.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that you have **merged** your new changes in the existing war, then you should follow below steps in order to see the effect of the new changes.

1. **Stop Jboss Server** (from services/ task manager(java.exe process))
2. In deployments folder keep only your projects **.war** file and readMe file if exists and delete all rest of file like (.undeployed etc.). Make sure there is only .war file.
3. Delete the entire **tmp** folder located inside standalone folder. (This is important)
4. **Restart Jboss server**, remember above three steps must be accomplishment .
5. Verify that your changes are reflected successfully.

Comment: Worked after deleting tmp files. OS is redhat

Comment: @Aadam, remember the tmp folder is the location where your application is extracted. For minor changes like small change in UI, css etc, you can use the jboss hot deployment way. it will help you to reduce your time for war deployment. here is some documentation https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Deployment+Scanner+configuration. If the changes are reflected using hot deployment then its good.